# What is generally the best approach reading a file for a compiler?

Tags: file, compiler-construction, token

I know this is a general question.

I'm going to program a compiler and I was wondering if it's better to take the tokens of the language while reading the file (i.e., first open the file, then extract tokens while reading, and finally close the file) or read the file first, close it and then work with the data in a variable. The pseudo-code for this would be something like:

```
file = open(filename);
textVariable = read(file);
close(file);

getTokens(textVariable);
```

The first option would be something like:

```
file = open(filename);
readWhileGeneratingTokens(file);
close(file);
```

I guess the first option looks better, since there isn't an additional cost in terms of main memory. However, I think there might be some benefits using the second option, for I minimize the time the file is going to be open.

Comment: when you say `program a compiler`, do you mean to write the whole compiler by yourself? In that case I would suggest using tools like lex and yacc to extract tokens and subsequent steps

Comment: Yes, I mean to write the whole compiler by myself. I know about those tools and they are, indeed, the best approach to do it. However, this is for an academic purpose and I'm not allowed to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide any hard data, but generally the amount of time a compiler spends tokenizing source code is rather small compared to the amount of time spent optimizing/generating target code.  Because of this, wanting to minimize the amount of time the source file is open seems premature.  Additionally, reading the entire source file into memory before tokenizing would prevent any sort of line-by-line execution (think interpreted language) or reading input from a non-file location (think of a stream like stdin).  I think it is safe to say that the overhead in reading the entire source file into memory is not worth the computer's resources and will ultimately be detrimental to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers are carefully designed to be able to proceed on as little as one character at a time from the input. They don't read entire files prior to processing, or rather they have no need to do so: that would just add pointless latency. They don't even need to read entire lines before processing.